# Horizontal Slider for shopping app

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontal-scrolling, horizontallist

Am working on a shopping app and want to implement the Horizontal Slider/Pager as shown in the screenshot.

[image: shopping app]

After a brief search found that I can use:

- View-pager
- Horizontal Grid-view (Library)

Please Suggest the best Layout i can use for this. OR Suggest a better way to implement this if you have already worked on such Views.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use [Multi View Pager](https://github.com/Pixplicity/MultiViewPager)

Comment: you're welcome buddy. If that helped you can voteup as a thank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have recently develop horizontal scrolling view using RecyclerView with a LinearLayoutManager. I used to do it using an Horizontal Scroll View with a linear layout inside but I never was a big fan of this approach.

I liked the RecyclerView approach because it work really like ListView and allow you to implement ViewHolder pattern. You have to set a  RecyclerView.Adapter instead of a classical Adapter.

You can follow the example here

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

To make the recycler view horizontal you have to set its layout manager with horizontal orientation :

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Now we have to do: `mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use HorizontalScrollView also but i would recommend you to go with Horizontal Grid-view (Library).